# How to plot two data sets with different time interval and have them share axis in Python Matplotlib

Tags: python, datetime, matplotlib

I have two data sets, A and B:

Set A: 
<kbd>date time</kbd>                 <kbd>data</kbd>
<kbd>6/21/2016 00:00:01</kbd>     <kbd>1</kbd>
<kbd>6/21/2016 01:00:00</kbd>     <kbd>2</kbd>
<kbd>6/21/2016 02:03:00</kbd>     <kbd>3</kbd>

Set B: 
<kbd>date time</kbd>                 <kbd>data</kbd>
<kbd>6/21/2016 00:01:10</kbd>    <kbd>10</kbd>
<kbd>6/21/2016 01:02:00</kbd>    <kbd>20</kbd>
<kbd>6/21/2016 01:23:00</kbd>    <kbd>30</kbd>
<kbd>6/21/2016 01:30:00</kbd>    <kbd>40</kbd>
<kbd>6/21/2016 02:01:00</kbd>    <kbd>50</kbd>

I am able to plot two sets on two separate plots with roughly the same start and end time stamp.  (in actuality, Set B increment is 5 second, Set A increment is 1 minute)

What I want to do is:
1) Fill both Set A and Set B with seconds (see below table). 
2) Empty data is OK, it should be ignored by matplotter 
3) Plot with new date-time 
Purpose: I want to do this is to combine multiple data source (datetime-temperature, datetime-datalogger, etc) with single time line.

My questions:
a) Is there a pre-built algorithm (matplotlib, datetime, some other modules) to accomplish 1)?
b) If a) is a negative, what is the best way to accomplish 1)?
c) Is there a better (easier) way to accomplish the purpose?

Set A: 
<kbd>date time</kbd>                 <kbd>data</kbd>
<kbd>6/21/2016 00:00:01</kbd>     <kbd>1</kbd>
<kbd>6/21/2016 00:00:02</kbd>      
<kbd>6/21/2016 00:00:03</kbd>      
...
<kbd>6/21/2016 00:59:58</kbd>      
<kbd>6/21/2016 00:59:59</kbd>      
<kbd>6/21/2016 01:00:00</kbd>     <kbd>2</kbd>
<kbd>6/21/2016 01:00:01</kbd>      
<kbd>6/21/2016 01:00:02</kbd>      
...
<kbd>6/21/2016 02:02:58</kbd>      
<kbd>6/21/2016 02:02:59</kbd>      
<kbd>6/21/2016 02:03:00</kbd>     <kbd>3</kbd>

Set B: 
<kbd>date time</kbd>                 <kbd>data</kbd>
<kbd>6/21/2016 00:00:01</kbd>      
<kbd>6/21/2016 00:00:02</kbd>      
...
<kbd>6/21/2016 00:01:08</kbd>      
<kbd>6/21/2016 00:01:09</kbd>      
<kbd>6/21/2016 00:01:10</kbd>    <kbd>10</kbd>
<kbd>6/21/2016 00:01:11</kbd>      
<kbd>6/21/2016 00:01:12</kbd>      
...
<kbd>6/21/2016 02:00:58</kbd>      
<kbd>6/21/2016 02:00:59</kbd>      
<kbd>6/21/2016 02:01:00</kbd>    <kbd>50</kbd>
...
<kbd>6/21/2016 02:02:59</kbd>      
<kbd>6/21/2016 02:03:00</kbd>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Skipping right to question (c), if it were me, I wouldn't bother filling both datasets with second resolution. Instead I would do a simple `pd.merge` and plot.

```
df_C = pd.merge(df_A, df_B, how='outer', left_index=True, right_index=True)
# forward fill data
df_C.ffill(inplace=True)
```

Now `df_C` is

```
In [68]: df_c
Out[68]: 
                     dataA  dataB
2016-06-21 00:00:01    1.0    NaN
2016-06-21 00:01:10    1.0   10.0
2016-06-21 01:00:00    2.0   10.0
2016-06-21 01:02:00    2.0   20.0
2016-06-21 01:23:00    2.0   30.0
2016-06-21 01:30:00    2.0   40.0
2016-06-21 02:01:00    2.0   50.0
2016-06-21 02:03:00    3.0   50.0
```

Then simply call `df_C.plot()` to plot your data.

---

If you'd like to have second resolution anyway, you can do so by resetting the index with a `pd.date_range`

```
df_C.reindex(pd.date_range(df_C.index.min(), df_C.index.max(), freq='s'))
```